# How and where properly connect and end mongoDB connection in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

Hi guys i have this pice of code (https://github.com/MrRav3n/Angular-Marketplace/blob/master/server.js) and i wonder if i correctly stard and end my database connection. Do i have to connect and end db connection in every `app.route` or is it correct to start database connection and end it at the end of the file?

Pls check my code and give me feedback.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you don't need to connect db in every route. Just make sure you connects before doing any operations on db and also close the connections after requirements are completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mongoose
.connect(
"mongodb+srv://MrRav3n:DAW100kr@cluster0-6xfty.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
.then(result => {
app.listen(3000);
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I recommend you install this package "moongose" a put the code above at the end of your code. source: Udemy Course "NodeJS - The Complete Guide (incl. MVC, REST APIs, GraphQL)"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any need to connect multiple times to your database. In fact one could put all the routes that depend on the database into the callback of the connect.